# How to batch a nested list of graphs in pytorch geometric

Tags: pytorch, batching, pytorch-geometric

I am currently training a model which is a mix of graph neural networks and LSTM. However that means for each of my training sample, I need to pass in a list of graphs. The current batch class in torch_geometric supports batching with `torch_geometric.data.Batch.from_data_list()` but this only allows one graph for each data point. How else can I go about batching the graphs?

Comment: Did you find a proper way to do this? I am running into the same issue where I want to put N graphs into one big super graph. But I have no clue how to start even with the top rated answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use diagonal batching:

https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/batching.html

Simply, you will put all the graphs as subgraphs into one big graph. All the subgraphs will be isolated.

See the example from TUDataset:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing